# Examples of TRO $V $ and $C^{\ast} $-algebra $B $ for which $V\otimes^hB $ is a TRO

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $V $ be a ternary ring of operator(TRO) and $B $ be a $\mathbb {C}^{\ast} $-algebra. Let $V \otimes^hB $ denotes the Haagerup tensor product of $V $ and $B $. Obviously if $V $ or $B $ is $\mathbb {C} $ then $V \otimes^h B $ is a TRO. Moreover, setting $V=C_n $, the column space then as $C_n\otimes^h B= C_n (B) $ therefore $V \otimes^h B $ is a TRO.

> What are some other interesting examples of TRO $V $ and $C^{\ast} $-algebra $B $ such that $V\otimes^hB $ is a TRO.